# move element left to right over and over jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm using this to move a div inside a slide show. The problem is that the captions for each image must move from left to right on each image starting from the same place (each div). 
Using this piece of code the div moves as desired but the next one will move from the point where the last one was placed.

```
$("#elementId").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100"
    }, 1000, function() {
        //Complete
    }
);
```

Just in case I'm making it hard to explain.

I have a slideshow, each image fades in, a sec later a div with some text show up on top of each image, the div must move from left to right. but using the code above, the div moves, but as soon as the next image fades in the div will move starting from the last position where the previous div was.

How can I make the div "move" again starting from 0 or the original position ?

**Edit** 
Code requested:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Speed of the automatic slideshow
    var slideshowSpeed = 6000;

    // Variable to store the images we need to set as background
    // which also includes some text and url's.


    var photos = [ {
            "title" : "First Tag line :",
            "image" : "/images/chrysanthemum-266x200.jpg",
            "url" : "http://www.gyms-ireland.com",
            "firstline" : "First Tag line :",
            "secondline" : "Second Tag line"
        }, {
            "title" : "Some text",
            "image" : "/images/tulips-oop-ll-266x200.jpg",
            "url" : "http://www.gyms-ireland.com",
            "firstline" : "Some text",
            "secondline" : "Alternative text"
        }, {
            "title" : "Npthing Here",
            "image" : "/images/koala-266x200.jpg",
            "url" : "http://www.gyms-ireland.com",
            "firstline" : "Npthing Here",
            "secondline" : "Also nothing here",
        }, {
            "title" : "Office Appartments",
            "image" : "/images/work.jpg",
            "url" : "http://www.sxc.hu/photo/1265695",
            "firstline" : "Or still busy at",
            "secondline" : "work?"
        }
    ];

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // Backwards navigation
        jQuery("#back").click(function() {
            stopAnimation();
            navigate("back");
        });

        // Forward navigation
        jQuery("#next").click(function() {
            stopAnimation();
            navigate("next");
        });

        var interval;
        jQuery("#control").toggle(function(){
            stopAnimation();
        }, function() {
            // Change the background image to "pause"
            jQuery(this).css({ "background-image" : "url(images/btn_pause.png)" });

            // Show the next image
            navigate("next");

            // Start playing the animation
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                navigate("next");
            }, slideshowSpeed);
        });


        var activeContainer = 1;    
        var currentImg = 0;
        var animating = false;
        var navigate = function(direction) {
            // Check if no animation is running. If it is, prevent the action
            if(animating) {
                return;
            }

            // Check which current image we need to show
            if(direction == "next") {
                currentImg++;
                if(currentImg == photos.length + 1) {
                    currentImg = 1;
                }
            } else {
                currentImg--;
                if(currentImg == 0) {
                    currentImg = photos.length;
                }
            }

            // Check which container we need to use
            var currentContainer = activeContainer;
            if(activeContainer == 1) {
                activeContainer = 2;
            } else {
                activeContainer = 1;
            }

            showImage(photos[currentImg - 1], currentContainer, activeContainer);

        };

        var currentZindex = -1;
        var showImage = function(photoObject, currentContainer, activeContainer) {
            animating = true;

            // Make sure the new container is always on the background
            currentZindex--;

            // Set the background image of the new active container
            jQuery("#headerimg" + activeContainer).css({
                "background-image" : "url(" + photoObject.image + ")",
                "display" : "block",
                "z-index" : currentZindex
            });

            // Hide the header text
            jQuery("#headertxt").css({"display" : "none"});

            // Set the new header text
            jQuery("#firstline").html(photoObject.firstline);
jQuery("#firstline").css("marginLeft", "0").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100"
    }, 4000, function() {
        //Complete
    }
);
            jQuery("#secondline")
                .attr("href", photoObject.url)
                .html(photoObject.secondline);
            jQuery("#pictureduri")
                .attr("href", photoObject.url)
                .html(photoObject.title);


            // Fade out the current container
            // and display the header text when animation is complete
            jQuery("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery("#headertxt").css({"display" : "block"});
                    animating = false;
                }, 500);
            });
        };

        var stopAnimation = function() {
            // Change the background image to "play"
            jQuery("#control").css({ "background-image" : "url(images/btn_play.png)" });

            // Clear the interval
            clearInterval(interval);
        };

        // We should statically set the first image
        navigate("next");

        // Start playing the animation
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            navigate("next");
        }, slideshowSpeed);

    });</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="headerimgs">
    <div id="headerimg1" class="headerimg"></div>
    <div id="headerimg2" class="headerimg"></div>
</div>

<!-- Slideshow controls -->

<!-- jQuery handles for the text displayed on top of the images -->
<div id="headertxt">
    <p class="caption">
        <span id="firstline"></span>
        <a href="#" id="secondline"></a>
    </p>
    <p class="pictured">
        Pictured:
        <a href="#" id="pictureduri"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    height: 220px;
    width: 520px;
}
.headerimg {
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
}

#headertxt {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 520px;
}
#firstline {
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    marginLeft:0px !important;
}
#secondline {
    clear: both;
    color: #CD2B3A;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 10px 30px 0;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#headerimgs a {
    text-indent: -999999px;
}

.new {
    display: block;
    height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
}
#secondline:hover { text-decoration:underline; color:#7F000C; }

.pictured {
    background-color: #CC3333;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 9px 16px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code

Comment: We'll need some details on your markup, styles, and the rest of your script in order to answer this one.

Comment: Edited question with full code. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Your question starts off saying you're using `animate`. Your edit with "full code" doesn't have any calls to `animate`, which pretty fundamentally changes the question! Where in that code is the initial example meant to be?

Comment: I never mentioned 'animate', Sorry but in the code pasted I forgot to place the `jQuery("#firstline").css("marginLeft", "0").animate({`

Comment: @user983248: *"I never mentioned 'animate'"* Huh?! Your question starts with "I'm using this to move a div inside a slide show" which is followed by a code snippet ***using `animate`***. That's kind of mentioning it.

Comment: OK thanks, please forget about it, already looks like one of these questions that everybody will down vote without provide an answer, just because a little technicality. Thanks any way.

Comment: @user983248: No, I think the problem is that the question was unclear and then went all over the place. If you'd put a bit of effort into the question in the first place, you'd probably have an answer by now. By the time you'd posted actual code that didn't contradict what you'd said you were doing, the question was off the front page. A minimal replicating test case might help.

Comment: Yhea sure, As I say before I just pasted the wrong piece of code, but that is enough for people to start to hammer others peoples head. As I said before Thanks, go to work and don't waste your time on this unless you wish to solve and answer the question.

Comment: @user983248: I just couldn't see why resetting `marginLeft` didn't work, and it was driving me nuts, so I copied all of the above to http://jsbin.com/usecef And with the `marginLeft` reset (per my answer, and now in your code above) it seems to work just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: What a heck !!! I can't find now where is the problem, booth codes are the same, but yours is working mine not.

Comment: @user983248: (If you don't do the @ thing, I don't get notified of your comment). Does your page have a `doctype`? jQuery doesn't work reliably in quirks mode (and I don't think they want or plan to support it). That's the only thing I can think of...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done, I just copy and paste the code as in your test page and nothing, after a close look There was an non closed div and I was echoing the whole javascript two times without knowing (i'm using php to echo the script as part of a function) I guess I need to go to bed, Sorry and TANKS, +1 , +1 and accepted answer

Comment: @user983248: I'm glad we got to the bottom of it. :-) Best,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep the only thing to know now is why the script stops on the last image, since that was not the normal behavior of the script before :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the question, but if you're re-using the same `div`, you'll need to reset `marginLeft`. E.g.:

```
$("#elementId").css("marginLeft", "0").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100"
    }, 1000, function() {
        //Complete
    }
);
```

(Of course, if the starting point shouldn't be `0`, use `10px` or whatever.) You might also want to throw a `stop` on there in case you call this before the animation completes, but it depends on what the rest of your code is doing.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ohiqin) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ohiqin/edit):

HTML:

```
<div id="elementId">I'm the div</div>
<button id="theButton">Click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    $("#elementId").stop().css("marginLeft", "0").animate({
            marginLeft: "-=100"
        }, 1000, function() {
            //Complete
            display("Done, click the button again to see the repeat");
        }
    );
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

Comment: @user983248: Did the above not answer the question?

Comment: @user983248: The "full code" doesn't even call `animate`...?! Sorry, will have to leave it to someone else to sort out, I have to get to work... Good luck,

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, code should been 'if (photoObject.firstline != "") {

jQuery("#firstline").css("marginLeft", "0").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100"
    }, 4000, function() {
        //Complete
    }
);'

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can see this has been solved, but I'd have used the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin; much more simple. You can see it in action on [my website](http://jamesswright.co.uk/).