# Make element move and when it disappears at the end of the screen make it appear again at the beginning of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

To clarify what I'm trying to do:

I have a fixed background image which should move slightly when the user scrolls, which is already working. But when the image disappears I want it to appear again at the beginning of the screen.

The image is just an example, it will be a svg which is going to be 100% wide, so the image has to appear at the screen again as soon as it has left: 1px already.

How do I do that?

Here's my code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaMJyG

```js
    var offset = $("#moving-element").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      $("#moving-element").css("left", st + offset.left);
    });
```

```css
    body {
      height: 9999px
    }
    
    #moving-element {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      background:   url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/nintendo/images/5/5c/Jumping_Mario_Artwork_-_New_Super_Mario_Bros._Wii.png/revision/latest?cb=20120318204810&path-prefix=en');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: bottom left;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moving-element">  
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move element left to right over and over jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579100/move-element-left-to-right-over-and-over-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Update variable st by st%width , where width is div width. So whenever , it becomes more than div width, it again resets automatically

```
var offset = $("#moving-element").offset();
var width = $("#moving-element").width();
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  st = st%width;
  $("#moving-element").css("left", st + offset.left);
});
```